# URL in UITextField on iOS 13 is trimmed

Tags: ios, url, uitextfield, ios13

I'm setting URL as string on UITextField like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string:"http://127.0.0.1/test_0/test_1/test_2/test_3/test_4.txt")
    self.textField.text = url?.absoluteString
}
```

But since iOS 13.0 presentation has changed: URL is trimmed to closest directory instead of adding ***...*** as on iOS 12.2. Check how URL presentation differs on iOS 12.2 and iOS 13.0:
[image]
[image]

Does anybody now how to make UITextField treat URL the same way as on iOS 12.2?

Comment: Do you want to prevent it from trimming?

Comment: Yes, on iOS 13 I'd like to have the same look as on iOS 12.2

Comment: @MaximMakhun do both strings have same values at the time of assignment?

Comment: Yes, no differences between two URLs. I've checked absoluteString value and they're the same as well.

Comment: What happens when you set string directly. I mean, self.textField.text = "http://127.0.0.1/test_0/test_1/test_2/test_3/test_4.txt"

Comment: No changes if I set string directly.

Comment: Issue was fixed in iOS 13 beta 5.